# Getting mouse movement value with DirectX Tool Kit

Tags: directx, directx11, input, mouse

today I want to ask a question about how to get mouse movement value with DirectX Tool Kit.

While I can certainly use `Mouse::SetMode(MODE_RELATIVE)`, to do this, I want to be able to get the mouse cursor position at the same time (which can only be done with `MODE_ABSOLUTE`).

The method I thought of involves leaving mouse mode as the default `MODE_ABSOLUTE`, and then subtract the mouse position from the previous frame from that of the current one.
But with this method, the mouse cursor can jump out of the window.

So I thought of restricting the mouse cursor to a certain point, but this obviously prevents me from calculating the movement value with said method.

Does anyone have some ideas on how to achieve this with DirectX Tool Kit ?
Or am I missing some obvious thing ? 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally speaking, you *either* use absolute coordinates -or- you use relative mouse coordinates. Both at the same time isn't particularly useful. If you do need both, then you should just keep it in the absolute mode and keep track of the previous frame's x/y location to compute the delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you just want the delta mouse when you are in relative mode.

According to the [mouse documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Mouse), when you query the state of the mouse, the x and y coordinates return the delta.

Note, because you are in relative mode and the mouse is locked, the mouse is likely always in the center of the window so any fixed position is worthless. (You could always use the native APIs to get it's true position if you so desire)

Comment: For Windows desktop, ``Mouse`` uses ``WM_INPUT`` so the system mouse cursor is hidden and 'locked' to the applications window. When you return to absolute mode, I move the mouse to the position it was at when you entered relative mode. For Windows Runtime apps, the system cursor position is 'locked' in the last position it was before entering relative mode as well.